What's the name of the Hollywood version of Seven Samurai?
I remember a movie that has the same story as Shichinin no Samurai (Akira Kurosawa), but in western style. 
So, i can't remember it's name.
Can anybody tell me the western movie's name which some farmers using 7 gangsters to protect their village against robbers?

That would be The Magnificent Seven:

The Magnificent Seven is a 1960 American western film directed by John Sturges. It is a western-style remake based on Akira Kurosawa's 1954 Japanese film Seven Samurai. The film stars Yul Brynner, Steve McQueen, Charles Bronson, James Coburn, Robert Vaughn, Brad Dexter, and Horst Buchholz who play a group of seven American gunmen hired to protect a small agricultural village in Mexico from a group of marauding native bandits led by Calvera, portrayed by Eli Wallach. The film's musical score was composed by Elmer Bernstein.


thanks a lot, i trying to remember at least one actor, within two days.

coleopterist is correct in identifying The Magnificent Seven, but there is more than remake of the Seven Samurai!! The late, great Schlock-Movie director Roger Corman made Battle Beyond the Stars (1980), a space-opera version.. which amusingly also features Robert Vaughn! Fun fact, fact fans..

Robert Vaughn also appeared in regularly in the 1998-2000 TV series of The Magnificent Seven, though as Orrin Travis, a circuit Judge, not one of the seven.
